# large resolution takes image from drawable instead of drawable-xxhdpi

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

in  my xamarin application I have set images in drawable and other folders of resources according to resolution

when i run application in tablet it takes image from drawable folder instead of drawable-xxhdpi?

why?

any idea?
please help

Comment: Which DPI does the tablet use?

Comment: @cheesebaron how can we know that?

Comment: i use samsung galaxy p7500 device

Comment: 800 x 1280 pixels, 16:10 ratio (~149 dpi density) according to GSMArena. Try checking what Android reports the DPI of the screen to be with: `Resources.DisplayMetrics`. But seemingly, this device is a mdpi device and not xxhdpi.

Comment: when i run application in my mobile than it takes image from xhdpi.so i assumed tablet is bigger than phone so obviously it will take larger image from xhdpi that is xxhdpi.isnt it?

Comment: It depends on the screen size and resolution. Most newer phones use a bigger resolution than that tablet. So the assumption is incorrect.

Comment: oh..then how decide which size of image i should put in which drawable folder which will look perfect in smaller to bigger device?

Comment: till now i was trying to put any image in xhdpi and if it looks great in my phone then i put its related ratio images in other drawable folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments. The device you are running on Samsung Galaxy P7500 has a resolution of 800x1280 pixels with a density of ~149 dpi. This means that it will take drawables from the folder nearest to its density, which is the `mdpi` folder.

Looking at the [official Android documentation from Google about Supporting Multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) you will find the following table:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Table 3 also explains your situation very well.

In any case when running on a Tablet with a 10" screen and resolution of 800x1280 pixels, the app will not attempt to get resources from any xhdpi, xxhdpi folder, but rather the mdpi folder, because the screens dpi matches that. You need to provide your resources there to support that tablet in particular.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and help.
but i dont know users of the app will use which device with which resolution.?the how can decide image sizes to create responsive UI for all devices.as you said i need to put images that looks good in 10'' tab to mdpi folder.

Comment: mdpi is the base dpi, so what looks good on your tablet, take those resources and multiply with 1.5 for hdpi, 2.0 for xhdpi, 3.0 for xxhdpi and 4.0 for xxxhdpi and 0.5 for ldpi. It is all described in the document I linked